# Shopify API how to do a search query with like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Hey guys I try to do some searching functions but it is not possible with shopifyAPI gem

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, conditions: ["title LIKE ?", "%#search%"], params: {limit: 20, page: 1})
```

With this function I got all products.

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, conditions: ["title LIKE ?", "%#search%"])
```

The same I got all products

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.search(parameters)
```

I found this function in this example but it is not a function anymore
 => ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/ruby-shopifyapi-find-customer-by-email-215330

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.where({ "title LIKE ?" =>"%#{search}%" })
```

With this one I got all products, again

This is the shopify_api gem => help.shopify.com/api/reference/product. 
This is the shopify_api => help.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me like the Shopify API supports this. What you're trying to do looks like ActiveRecord querying, but this gem only provides an Active Record-like syntax.

The API does support searching based on product title, so perhaps you may be able to specify a single word or two from the product name it and it will match those?

Comment: Not, it does not match anything, single word or two. I do not know how Shopify can do it. Thank Ryan

Answer (score 1):

You can use direct fields to search like:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10, 
                                         title: params[:title],               
                                         page: params[:page] })
```